# SQL Server : select row_number() is not clear

Tags: sql-server

this Stored procedure creates a test table and inserts some dummy values into it. I couldn't get this:

> SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)

What is a.n? Where is 'a', and 'n'? There is an 'a' in 'FROM t4 AS a' but that 'select' statement is different from this one, so I don't think it can be used from there to here

> ```
> CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable(
>       Col1 nchar(4000) NOT NULL
>       ,Col2 nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL
> );
>
>
> WITH 
>     t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
>     ,t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
>     ,t16M AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num FROM   t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b CROSS JOIN t256 AS c)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A is the alias you have given for the CTE called t256 (t256 AS a), which seems to be a table of 256 rows, where the column name is n and values are all zeros.

And the result of this is 16 777 216 rows, with numbers starting from 1.

Comment: I don't see "t256 AS a" in the stored proc. It only says "FROM t4 AS a". BTW, I didn't write this. So, trying to understand it. Please help.

Comment: Well it is there: "OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num FROM   t256 AS a" -- and probably all you need to understand is that this whole CTE returns a table numbers, from 1 to 16 million.

Comment: And it does that by joining the 4 zeros 4 times with itself, and then joining that result 3 times with itself, and the numbers of the table names are the amount of lines in it